# What is the safest way to save CurrentUser.id?

Tags: strapi

Dear Strapi team and fans,

I have a simple question:

I [created a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq55B.png) with the following setting:

In "Author" I want to save "CurrentUser.id". I can write in FrontEnd "Author = CurrentUser.id", which works, but this assignment can be manipulated in FrontEnd, right?

For security, it might be better if Author automatically gets the value of CurrentUser.id in BackEnd.

Do I have to change anything in Strapi BackEnd or is this functionality already available?

Thanks in advance!

Benjamin

PS: [Here is a screenshot. That's what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvXgR.png)

Comment: What do you mean by this assignment could be manipulated?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!
I programmed a simple Angular FrontEnd. - Log in and then write an article...
In the "form" there are only two fields "Title" and "Description". To save, I send the values of them with "jwt" and CurrentUser.id to the api. - Is that safe?
If a user changes the CurrentUser.id in JS, he can write an article as another user, right?
I have not tested this yet, but theoretically it is possible to manipulate the frontend in JS. As I see it, the CurrentUser.id (Author) should be determined through tokens and then added to the database, but I do not know how. :(

Comment: I added a screenshot. :)

Comment: How can I get the CurrentUser.id in backend? I just know how to get the value in frontend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation here https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/guides/authentication.html#user-object-in-strapi-context

When a user is authenticated and you request Strapi with, that set the User information in the context (ctx.state.user)

So if you want to auto apply the user id of en entry when you create it.
You have to customise the `create` function of your controller and add the `ctx.state.user.id` for the key you want of your `ctx.request.body`

In your case will be `./api/article/controllers/Article.js`
And for the the create function will look like that

```
create: async (ctx) => {
    ctx.request.body.author = ctx.state.user._id;
    return strapi.services.article.create(ctx.request.body);
  },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly this! :)